# Music and SFX Question on Memory Efficiency

Tags: libgdx, music, memory-efficiency, sound-effects, extension

What should I recommend: MP3 or WAV for the SFX? Also, what should I do to handle the memory in music or SFX?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What quality should my sounds be?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20672/what-quality-should-my-sounds-be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both type of sound file, **WAV** and **MP3**, are okay but make sure you know how to stop the music through coding and you know LibGDX, right? Make sure that you can afford it depending on the device you're testing.

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. But, please, focus on your coding skills. Remember that everything is a suggestion. Only you can find the answer. Programmer takes time to learn, okay?